# Oracle Instant Client and LDAP

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g, odp.net

I am packaging the Oracle Instant Client DLLs with my application to standardize the Oracle client as well as provide one if the user doesn't have one installed.

Currently I need to use a full connection string to connect to the Oracle instances but would like to make use of the Oracle Directory Services to use LDAP to query the connection details for a given SID.

Is there a way to do this with ODT.Net or do I need to manually create and execute LDAP queries?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The Oracle client needs to have the TNS_Admin environment variable set. I C# all I needed to do was this:

```
 If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TNS_ADMIN"))) Then
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TNS_ADMIN", "MY\TNS\ADMIN\PATH")
 End If
```